# Как получить все значения отдельного элемента модели из бд django

Tags: python, django

Есть модель содержащая `login` и `password`. Нужно получить все логины в виде списка.

Я сделал это как-то так:

```
login_array = [[i for i in f.values()][0] 
               for f in Game_user.objects.values('login')]
```

Есть ли способ лучше и быстрее?
Нужно проверить нету ли такого логина в бд. Я решил это тем что получаю все логины из бд способом выше и просто проверяю:

```
if not login in login_array
```

Нету ли способа лучше как-то это сделать?

**Views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Game_user
import json


def login(request):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    login = json_data['login']
    password = json_data['password']
    login_array = [[i for i in f.values()][0] for f in Game_user.objects.values('login')]
    if login in login_array:
        db_user = Game_user.objects.get(login=login)
        if password == db_user.password:
            return JsonResponse({'success': True})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'success': False})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})

def signup(request):
    json_data = json.loads(request.body)
    login = json_data['login']
    password = json_data['password']
    login_array = [[i for i in f.values()][0] for f in Game_user.objects.values('login')]
    if not login in login_array:
        Game_user.objects.create(login=login,password=password)
        return JsonResponse({'success': True})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'success': False})
```

**models.py**

```
class Game_user(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='login')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='password')
```

Comment: Покажите файл models.py,пожалуйста!

Comment: '''class Game_user(models.Model):
    login = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='login')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='password')'''

Comment: Непонятно написано все смешано(в 2 строки)

Comment: Ну ладно,щас разберусь

Comment: Даже мне стало интересно как можно сделать быстрее,можете пожалуйста скинуть код views.py,urls.py(которые в приложении) и скиньте все html шаблоны которые есть и что бы код нормально читался выделяете код и нажимаете Cntr + K(англ K)

Comment: И добавьте код файлов в вопрос,ну т,е нажмите привить вопрос и добавьте код пж

Comment: У меня не веб приложения, а декстопное. Фрагмент кода с обращением на сервер тоже добавил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) вам не подойдет?

```
login = json_data['login']

if Game_user.objects.filter(login=login).exists():
    print('Такой логин существует')
```

Comment: можете в кратце объяснить что он делает?

Comment: @AlecsFly возвращает `True`, если по запросу `Game_user.objects.filter(login=login)` найден хотя бы один эелемент.

Comment: я написал так вроде бы должно было работать быстрее, но также ответ от сервера приходит только через 2 секунды. Как я понял это из-за сервера так да. Не знаете как это время можно сократить?

Comment: Ну думаю когда в бд много польователей это оч поможет

Comment: Я в контроллер поставил просто return и все равно ответ от сервера приходит только через 2 секунды. Не знаете как это время можно сократить?

Comment: @AlecsFly сложно сказать. попробуйте использовать [django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar/) и посмотреть, что именно работает медленно. Со встроенным сервером работает нормально?

Comment: Ну я именно локальный север запускаю через django. И оттуда так долго идет ответ.Я в views в функции оставил только `return JsonResponse({'success': True})` и он все равно возвращает ответ только через 2 секунды. Запрос отправляю с помощью библиотеки requests

Comment: @AlecsFly какой запрос вы делаете с помощью requests?

Comment: `self.user_info = {'login': self.ui_log.login.text(), 'password': self.ui_log.password.text()}`                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                        
`self.r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/user/login/', json=self.user_info).json()`

Comment: @AlecsFly это в каком-то из  view такой код? или вы из вашего десктопного приложения к бэкенду на джанго обращаетесь с помощью requests?

Comment: Это в приложении мой код. Ну через requests обращаюсь. А что есть какие то другие библиотеки лучше? Асинхронку я пока не знаю если что

Comment: 2 секунды было из-за того-что каждый раз я делал request.get запрос и он каждый раз открывал и закрывал канал связи. Воспользовался Session при запуске программы сразу кидаю session.get запрос чтобы откырть канал связи и все летает потом)

Answer (score 2):

У меня был аналогичный вопрос. Вот в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values) я наткнулся на хороший вариант с методом `values_list`, который возвращает кортежи. Чтобы получить в ответ не кортежи, а кверисет по одному значению, нужно добавить параметр `flat=True`.

Кстати, я еще добавил `distinct()`, чтобы получить список без дублей.

То есть получается как-то так в твоем случае:

```py
login_array = Game_user.objects.values_list('login', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: А чтобы получить в виде списка - нужно обернуть в `list()` чтобы привести к типу списка